# Show that the probability of its including exactly $k$ red elements is ${r \choose k} p^k q^{r-k}.$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-distribution

A population of $n$ elements includes $np$ red ones and $nq$ black ones ($p+q = 1$). A random sample of size $r$ is taken with replacement. Show that the probability of its including exactly $k$ red elements is 
$${r \choose k} p^k q^{r-k}.$$

Attempt: the probability should be $\frac{{np \choose k}{nq \choose r-k}}{{n \choose r}}$. By manipulating this, I get ${r \choose k} \frac{n-r \choose np-k}{n \choose np}$. So, the problem is reduced to finding the equality: $p^k q^{r-k} = \frac{n-r \choose np-k}{n \choose np}$. But, I am stuck here. How can I prove this equality?

Comment: "*The probability should be...*"  You seem to have misread the problem.  It says we are taking a sample **with** replacement, not without.  This is very simply the binomial distribution.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for pointing out.